# Yammer API. Use /messages/in_group/[:group_id].json for AllCompany

Tags: yammer

We use the https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messagesin_groupgroup_id

It works for us, for example for **exact group** we can execute this request:
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/118*******.json?network_id=Default&triggerstate=408119030538240&newer_than=408119030538240
It returns good Json response.

But we have trouble when we want to use it for AllCompany.
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/0.json?network_id=Default

How we should create request for **AllCompany** group? Could you provide the example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All company does not have a group id. Try using `https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/general.json`.

Comment: Also, do you know if this solution is documented anywhere? We are going to use it in our production environment and we should rely on documented methods, but I haven't found it in Yammer REST API docs.

Comment: I do not know about it being documented, sorry.